# Action Bar´s title on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to change the title of the Action Bar on a ListFragment. I am using this:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("aa");
```

but it says call requires API 11 and I am using 9 with support v4, how can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: aren't you using `appcompat` library for `ActionBar` ?

Comment: use getSupportAcionBar()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SherlockActionBar library for using Action Bar below API level 11.
Then call     getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("aa");

Comment: support library can be used for API 7>.refer here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to check the build version and setting Title and subtitle -

```
/**
 * Sets the Action Bar for new Android versions.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void actionBarSetup() {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setTitle("My Title");
    ab.setSubtitle("sub-title"); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works, hope this will help you:

```
int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title",
                "id", "android");

            TextView mAppName = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
    mAppName.setText("your title here ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need support library v7 `AppCompat` and use `ActionBarActivity` instead of either `Activity` or `FragmentActivity`.

Once you're using `ActionBarActivity` you should call `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title)`